# Is there a better way to condense the while loop?

Tags: python

I have been trying to write a number guessing game and I am trying to condense the second while loop when guess =! random_number. 
I can't figure out if there is any better way to shorten the code but to still achieve the same result. I wonder if someone is able to help me out. 
 If there's anything else which is redundant or not efficient in my code or how i could code it better please criticize the hell out me my work!

```
import random

def inputNumber(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            return userInput
            break

#ranges must be integers
min_range = int(inputNumber("Please insert the min range: "))
temp_range = int(inputNumber("Please insert the max range: "))

#max range must be bigger than min
while min_range >= temp_range:
    temp_range = int(inputNumber("Please insert a max range which is smaller than min range!: ")) + 1

max_range = temp_range

random_number = random.randint(min_range, max_range)

guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
counter = 1;  # you guessed once already
while guess != random_number:  # 1 guess incorrect
    print(f"{random_number} is the random number")# to see for myself which is the random numb
    if min_range < guess < max_range:  # WITHIN THE RANGE
        if random_number - random_number / 12 < guess-random_number < random_number + random_number / 12:  # 3 super hot
            print("Please try again, you are super hot!")
        elif random_number - random_number / 8 < guess-random_number < random_number + random_number / 8:  # 3 hot
            print("Please try again, you are hot!")
        elif guess < random_number - random_number / 2 or guess-random_number > random_number + random_number / 2:  # 3 cold
            print("Please try again, you are cold!")

    else:  # OUTSIDE RANGE
        print("You are outside the range, try again!")
    guess = int(input())
    counter += 1
if guess == random_number:  # guess correct
    print(f"Congratulations, you guessed correctly in {counter} tries!")
```

edit: thanks you all so much for taking the time to review my code, i will try to improve on the noted points, much appreciated (:

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miscellaneous notes:

- you don't need a `break` after a `return`
- you could (attempt to) return directly from the input; "except" will still catch and cycle errors
- `inputNumber()` explicitly returns an integer; no need to cast again.
- `temp_range` isn't really needed - you can just use `max_range`, no loss to readability.
- no need to add one to `max_range` (in the validation loop) - `randint()` includes the top limit.
- `random_number` is an unhelpful variable name - I've called this `target`
- using `inputNumber()` for the `guess` also seems sensible.
- `guess` should be checked against the **inclusive** range - min and max are possible values.
- *personally* I think the temperature categories should reflect the size of the range, rather than the size of the chosen number... however
- your calculation is wrong anyway; you are testing the difference between `guess` and `target` so you should test against the small fraction of `target`, not `target` reduced by a fraction (or should just check `guess` against the numbers you calculate).
- the "hot" range (outside "super hot") is actually smaller than the "super hot" range - I adjusted this out to 1/4 of `target`
- after correction, there's a range that gets no message, which can be covered in an `else` clause. I reordered so all tests are for "in this range" and the `else` covers the "cold" option.

To condense the message selection, you could set up a list of boundaries changing from one condition to another, and step through (or search) to find the applicable message. However I'm not sure that's a lot clearer in this case.

With updates reflecting most of these:

````py
import random
CHEATING = True

def inputNumber(message):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")

#ranges must be integers
min_range = inputNumber("Please insert the min range: ")
max_range = inputNumber("Please insert the max range: ")

#max range must be bigger than min
while min_range >= max_range:
    max_range = inputNumber("Please insert a max range which is bigger than min range!: ")

target = random.randint(min_range, max_range)

guess = inputNumber("Please enter your guess: ")
counter = 1;  # you guessed once already
while guess != target:  # 1 guess incorrect
    if CHEATING: print(f"{target} is the random number")# to see for myself which is the random numb
    if min_range <= guess <= max_range:  # WITHIN THE RANGE
        if  -target / 12 < guess-target < target / 12:  # 3 super hot
            print("Please try again, you are super hot!")
        elif  -target / 4 < guess-target < target / 4:  # 3 hot
            print("Please try again, you are hot!")
        elif -target / 2 < guess-target < target / 2:   # a bit meh
            print("Not great, not terrible - please try again")
        else:                                           # 3 cold
            print("Please try again, you are cold!")

    else:  # OUTSIDE RANGE
        print("You are outside the range, try again!")
    guess = inputNumber("Next guess? ")
    counter += 1
if guess == target:  # guess correct
    print(f"Congratulations, you guessed correctly in {counter} tries!")```
````

PS: "please criticize the hell out my work" is an excellent attitude, if you have the fortitude for it, and a great way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest sources of repetition in your code are the mathematical
calculations of the difference between the random number and the user's guess,
along with the need to re-ask the user for another guess on a couple of
occasions. You already have a function to get an integer from the user, so take
advantage of it! Also, you could enhance that function to eliminate the need to
repeat yourself when collecting `max_range`. Finally, I did not
fully understand the intended logic of your difference calculation,
so I improvised to use a modified approach
(percentage difference relative to the overall span of the range). In any case,
the important point is to **make the calculation once**. Then use the result to
select the adjective. Some possible edits for you to consider:

```
import random

# An enhanced function taking an optional minimum value.
# If needed, you could enhance further by changing that
# parameter to a `range()` if you want to restrict both sides.
# If you were do to that, you could further simplify the
# guessing loop.
def inputNumber(message, min_val = 0):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(message))
            if n >= min_val:
                return n
            else:
                print(f"Must be greater than {min_val}. Try again")
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")

# No need to convert these values to integers.
# The function already does that.
min_range = inputNumber("Please insert the min range: ")
max_range = inputNumber("Please insert the max range: ", min_val = min_range)
random_number = random.randint(min_range, max_range)
counter = 0

# When getting user input, a while-True loop is usually
# the right way to start. If you ask before the loop,
# you have to re-ask if the user makes a mistake.
while True:
    counter += 1
    guess = inputNumber("Please enter your guess: ")
    if guess == random_number:
        print(f"Congratulations, you guessed correctly in {counter} tries!")
        break
    # This comparison should use <= rather than < I think.
    elif min_range <= guess <= max_range:
        diff_pct = abs(guess - random_number) / (max_range - min_range)
        adjective = (
            'super hot' if diff_pct < .2 else
            'hot' if diff_pct < .4 else
            'cold'
        )
        print(f"Please try again, you are {adjective}!")
    else:
        print("You are outside the range, try again!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add some points to [Joffan's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260993/239401), which already provides some great improvements.

---

**Naming**

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names): Variable and function names should follow snake_case instead of camelCase.

---

**input_number**

This function should be a lot simpler:

```
def input_number(message):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")
```

---

**main()**

It's a good idea to wrap your procedure into a `main()` function, which provides a standard entry point. It also makes the functionality of your code clearer at a glance. Since a function will not run on its own when we execute the script, we need to call it. For most use cases, we should wrap it in a `if __name__ == “__main__”:` condition.

```
def main():
    # this is where your procedure now runs

if __name__ == “__main__”:
    main()
```

[What does if **name** == “**main**”: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)